# How would I find any symlinks on my system that reference "/tmp"?

Tags: find, symlink

I need to create a list of all symlinks that reference the /tmp directory. How many are there in total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crude but effective:

find / -warn -xdev -name "*" -type l -exec ls -l {} + | grep ' /tmp'

(BTW, no matches at all on my system)